# rtsp audio+video using Gstreamer Android

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to construct a RTSP pipeline on the client side to receive audio and video streams on android platform

Only video pipeline works fine

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.100:8554/ss ! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse !  amcviddec-omxtiducati1videodecoder  ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink",&error);
```

I need to receive audio streams also, so I tried with below pipeline

```
gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.100:8554/ss  demux. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink demux. ! queue ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! ffdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

Gstreamer throws error saying no element `"demux"`

Please let me know proper rtsp pipeline to receive audio and video streams on android

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, (tested):

`gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.100:8554/ss  name=demux. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink demux. ! queue ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! ffdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink`